# Backendless API documentation incorrect?

Tags: swift, backendless

Here is the code:

```
let queryBuilder = DataQueryBuilder()
queryBuilder.setWhereClause(whereClause: "age = 47")   <---but this doesn't exist in the code.
```

The "setWhereClause" is not a member of queryBuilder. Is there updated documentation somewhere?
is there something wrong in my pod? I just verified I have the latest version.

Comment: So the source (might help) is https://backendless.com/docs/ios/data_search_with_where_clause.html

Comment: Seems to be there https://github.com/Backendless/Swift-SDK/blob/fab7a79292554de6fa537ca90f172194457cf02a/Sources/SwiftSDK/Persistence/DataQueryBuilder.swift Maybe `queryBuilder.whereClause = "age = 47"`? I guess the doc for Swift might have generated on old Swift version.

Comment: ...yes might right...maybe an old swift version because setWhereClause doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with this statement:

```
queryBuilder.whereClause = "age = '47'"
```

I wish they would update their tuts.